# Unable to boot from a usb that contains Ubuntu 20.04.5 lts

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, fwupd

I made a bootable USB using Ubuntu 20.04.5 while ago, and I didn't have any problems booting from it. But from two days ago, I couldn't boot from the USB. Other computers had no problems booting from it, so it's not the fault from the USB itself. One strange thing is that I made a bootable USB with the same device using Ubuntu 22.04 and then it worked.

My laptop is XPS 9310. When I plug in 20.04 bootable USB, press F12 to choose the boot device, the computer hangs in the middle while printing 'Preparing One Time Boot'. I did a little bit of my research and I am suspicious of UEFI dbx. Here is the output of `fwupdmgr get-history`

```
XPS 13 9310
│
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Device ID:          
│ │   Previous version:   3.9.0
│ │   Update State:       Success
│ │   Last modified:      2022-09-12 05:24
│ │   GUID:               
│ │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
│ │                       • Updatable
│ │                       • System requires external power source
│ │                       • Supported on remote server
│ │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │ 
│ └─XPS 13 9310:
│       New version:      3.10.0
│       Remote ID:        lvfs
│       Release ID:       15424
│       Summary:          Firmware for the Dell XPS 13 9310
│       License:          Proprietary
│       Size:             32.6 MB
│       Created:          2022-08-09
│       Urgency:          High
│       Vendor:           Dell
│       Description:      
│       This stable release fixes the following issues:
│       
│       • Fixed the issue where the system stops responding at the Dell logo while booting.
│     
└─UEFI dbx:
  │   Device ID:          
  │   Previous version:   83
  │   Update State:       Failed
  │   Update Error:       failed to run update on reboot
  │   Last modified:      2022-09-17 07:54
  │   GUID:               
  │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
  │                       • Updatable
  │                       • Supported on remote server
  │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
  │ 
  └─  New version:      217
        Remote ID:        lvfs
        License:          Unknown
        Description:      
        The vendor did not supply any release notes.
```

And now I don't know how to fix the failed update in the firmware, nor the original problem with the bootable USB. Are these two related? And how do I fix them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- "One strange thing is that I made a bootable USB with the same device using Ubuntu 22.04 and then it worked".
- The computer is rather new, probably newer than the [original] 20.04 LTS (from April 2022).

These two observations make me think that some hardware or piece of BIOS software in your computer is too new for 20.04,x LTS. Fortunately the newer LTS version, 22.04, works, and I would recommend that you use that version.

Answer (score 0):

this seems related to the microsoft KB5012170 update, which blocks a lot of linux bootloaders. You could edit the DBX list. Maybe find a way to use the Ubunutu 22 bootloader with ubuntu 20?

also, do take care, if BitLocker or other encryption is used, that may get tripped by such edits, that you have recovery keys noted elsewhere.

Comment: I have tested with other laptops (not from Dell) and they worked fine. I don't know much about the boot and firmware stuff, but I checked their UEFI dbx version and the version number was higher in the other laptops. One laptop has a version number around 230. This dell one is the only laptop that has problems with booting USB that contains 20.04.5. If the reason of this problem is the microsoft update, then I guess other laptops must have the same problem...?

Comment: Based on the bios setup, I see dbx is part of the secure boot. So I turned off secure boot, but the problem didn't go away.

Comment: the microsoft KB update adds to the uefi blacklist, so if other laptops did not have that update, that would explain why the live usb stick would still work on those notebooks. 
I would indeed have expected that turning off secure boot would have made the USB stick boot again, although i'm no expert on the inner workings of secure boot.